# How to go to another view controller when button is pressed in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, function, button, swift3

This code is in OverlayView.swift

```
protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate {
func didCancel(overlayView: OverlayView)
func didShoot(overlayView: OverlayView)
}

class OverlayView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraLabel: UILabel!

var delegate: OverlayViewControllerDelegate! = nil


@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    cameraLabel.text = "I want to exit"
    delegate.didCancel(overlayView: self)


}
```

All i want to do is anytime the cancel button is clicked. Is make the the current page transform the page of view controller. I want to go from page a to page b.

Comment: what is `page a` and `page b`?

Answer (score 4):

1. It should be `OverlayViewDelegate` not `OverlayViewControllerDelegate` since it's not a controller from where you're sending the event, right? From `OverlayView`'s point of view it doesn't matter who is actually implementing this protocol but it's more important who is sending an event.
2. You probably have a view controller somewhere, which is going to `implement` this protocol:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, OverlayViewDelegate {
    //another code
    func didCancel(overlayView: OverlayView) {
         //show a new controller
    }
}
```

3. Showing a new controller programmatically.
   You can either present it modally or push it to navigation stack. First approach is preferable if you're gonna show only one controller and there is no deeper view controllers to show and second is for pushing more and more controllers into navigation stack.

Push to navigation stack:

```
let newViewController = AnotherViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) //your current vc should be already in a UINavigationController
```

Present modally example:

```
let newViewController = AnotherViewController()
self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

4. Showing a new controller using segues.
   You can create a segue in storyboard from one view controller to another by dragging with right button pressed. If you assign a storyboard id, you can then `perform` that segue from code like this:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: nil)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueIdentifier", sender: someUsefulData)
```

The segue itself can *push* or *present modally*, just pick a correct type when you create it.

5. **This is most probably your case.** If you already have a view controller presented and you want to go back, use [dismiss(animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismissviewcontrolleranimated) when you handle callback:

```
func didCancel(overlayView: OverlayView) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

6. If you already have a view controller pushed to navigation stack, you can go back by using [popViewController(animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller):

```
func didCancel(overlayView: OverlayView) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This code is part of app that features a nib thing to take photos. When the photo is taken for whatever reason the the cancel does not transport the user to the view controller it only shows a full screen image of the photo you have just taken. I want the cancel button to lead me back to the view controller weather or not you have taken a photo. I dont think the orginal code can change much because the code still has to take the photo. This is a video link explaining my problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIMmngzuUxY

Comment: @JCSAM Check the update. I guess you just need to `dismiss` your `overlay view controller` (p.5)

Answer (score 0):

Add these extensions to your project and you can get the view controller of a view using `parentViewController`.

```
//
//  UIResponder+NextType.swift
//
//  Created by Callam Poynter on 02/08/2016.
//

extension UIView {

    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {

        return next(UIViewController.self)
    }
}

extension UIResponder {

    func next<T: UIResponder>(_ type: T.Type) -> T? {

        switch next {

        case let responder as T:
            return responder

        case let .some(responder):
            return responder.next(type)

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a segue prepared in your storyboard with an identifier:

```
parentViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("fromPageAToB", sender: nil)
```

Or if you are instantiating the controller manually, you can present the controller using:

```
parentViewController?.presentViewController(pageBController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

If you'd prefer to not use these extensions and just use your delegate protocol instead, make sure the controller that is presenting the `OverlayView` conforms to the `OverlayViewDelegate` and you set the delegate of the `OverlayView` view to `self` in your controller.

Comment: Would this code replace all of the code I wrote before? I don't understand where the shoot button is and cancel is.

Comment: responding above.

Answer (score -1):

If your going to another view controller from a button you want to right click on that button and drag it to the next view controller and there you ll chose any method that you want to be presented to view the controller.